# How to compare hex values using AWK?

Tags: awk, debian

Consider using the following program that filters hex number in the range `0x10` - `0xa0`.

```
echo -e "0x10\n0xff\n0x16\n0x80\n0x50" | awk '$1 >= 0x10 && $1 <= 0xa0 { print $0 }'
```

The program works fine, if I replace all numbers using decimal equivalents, but fails with hex numbers.

The version of `awk` that I'm using doesn't support `--non-decimal-data` - it's the default version that comes with Debian 10 Buster.

How can I make the comparison work with hex numbers?

Comment: What range of values can the hex numbers have? 0x00 to 0xff or larger?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` has [`strtonum` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strtonum-Function.html) for this conversion from `hex` to `decimal`:

```sh
echo -e "0x10\n0xff\n0x16\n0x80\n0x50" |
awk '{n = strtonum($1)} n >= 0x10 && n <= 0xa0'

0x10
0x16
0x80
0x50
```

---

In absence of `gnu awk`, you may use this `perl` one liner also:

```sh
echo -e "0x10\n0xff\n0x16\n0x80\n0x50" |
perl -lane 'print if hex($F[0]) >= 0x10 && hex($F[0]) <= 0xa0'
```

Comment: A problem is that numbers may be so big that they are interpreted as negative integers, which is a problem. Also, are you sure `strtonum` is available in all versions of `awk`?

Comment: Sorry `strtonum` is not available across all awk

Comment: Yeah, my `awk` complains that it doesn’t exist :(

Comment: please try `perl` alternative

Answer (score 0):

one trick is doing string comparison instead.  Since "a">"9", this will work

```
$ echo -e "0x10\n0xff\n0x16\n0x80\n0x50" | 
  awk '$1 >= "0x10" && $1 <= "0xa0"'


0x10
0x16
0x80
0x50
```

Comment: Don’t this fail, if the numbers are not the same length? I.e `0x1000` is less than `0x80` using string comparison?

Comment: Right, it's not a generic solution but a working hack for a subset of the numbers with the same fixed length.